# How to connect Multiple MVC.net Application with other MVC.net Applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-routing

Is it possible to have an ASP.NET MVC Server that communicates with other MVC.net Applications? ( example is shown in image link )

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90C8m.jpg)
[image]

A client first communicates with the Main Server. The Main Server redirects his request to one of the other Servers. The client can't communicate directly with the other servers. It should always be via the Main Server.

So when a user requests MainServer.com

MainServer will direct the user to either on of the following:
    `S1.MainServer.com`
    `S2.MainServer.com`
    `S3.MainServer.com`

Note S1, S2 and S3 are physically separated from each other.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do server-server communications. One server could make an HTTP request to another, message queuing, data in the database, … What works for a specific case depends on the details of the functional and non-functional requirements as well as available infrastructure.

Comment: For sure. I'd look at either a service bus in the background (like EasyNetQ, MassTransit or Azure SB), or Web API's, but it's hard to say without knowing what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: May be a load balancer can do this for you easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!S1.Server.IsBusy())
    {
        return new RedirectResult("http://S1.MainServer.com");
    }
    else if(!S2.Server.IsBusy())
    {
        return new RedirectResult("http://S2.MainServer.com");
    }
    else if (!S3.Server.IsBusy())
    {
        return new RedirectResult("http://S3.MainServer.com");
    }
    else return View();
}
```